# Why do I get a "connection is already open" error during a MySQL update statement?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing a college attendance project with Winforms, MySQL, and C#.

In that I want to update "Total Absent" and "Total Present" in one table. So I wrote code for that:

```
int p = 0;
int a = 0;
string sno = "";

MySqlDataReader Reader;
command.CommandText = "select * from attendance_monthly_rpt";
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();           

while (Reader.Read())
{
    p = 0;
    a = 0;
    sno = Reader[1].ToString();
    for (int k = 3; k <= 33; k++)
    {
        if ((Reader[k].ToString() == "P") || (Reader[k].ToString() =="OD"))
        {
            p += 1;
        }
        else if (Reader[k].ToString() == "Ab")
        {
            a += 1;
        }
    }
}
connection.Close();
```

Now I get "sno", "a", "p" values for that. But I want to update this record in the MySQL table. So I added an `UPDATE` statement:

```
while (Reader.Read())
{
    p = 0;
    a = 0;
    sno = Reader[1].ToString();
    for (int k = 3; k <= 33; k++)
    {
        if ((Reader[k].ToString() == "P") || (Reader[k].ToString() =="OD"))
        {
            p += 1;
        }
        else if (Reader[k].ToString() == "Ab")
        {
            a += 1;
        }
    }           
    command.CommandText = "update attendance_monthly_rpt set tot_persent = " +
                          p + ", tot_absent = " + a + " where student_no = '" +
                          sno + "'";
    connection.Open();  // the connection is already open
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
connection.Close()
```

This throws the error *"The connection is already open"*. If I place the update statement after the loop, I get the last record only.

Please help me to update my "Tot absent", "Tot present" for each "Student".

Comment: use 2 different connection, one to update and one to select reader loop

Comment: Thanks. is i wanna use diff Connection only?. or Command also?.

Comment: I am not aware of rollback. so unfortunately i click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at your code after you've removed most of what's not related to opening or closing the connection:

```
…
connection.Open();       // <--------------+
…                        //                |
                         //                |
while (…)                //                |
{                        //                |
    …                    //                |
    connection.Open();   // the connection is already open
    …
    connection.Close();  // <--------------+
}                        //                |
connection.Close()       // likewise, it'll already be closed here
```

It's easy to see now why the connection is already open during the first run of the `while` loop.

**Apropos:** I would suggest that you *not* `.Open()` and `.Close()` the connection for every single command. (Connections should indeed not be kept open any longer than is necessary, but you're probably exaggerating it a little there. :) Instead, just open the connection once before you start your updates, and close it after the `while` loop. And, like CodeBuzz suggested already, put the `connection.Close()` in a `finally` block to make sure the connection is closed even if something goes wrong.

**P.S.:** Don't forget to `.Dispose()` all objects that are `IDisposable` (ie. the data reader and connection objects), e.g. via a `using` block.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this for checking connection's state :

```
if (myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    myConnection.Open();
}
```

and don't forget to use try, catch, and finally

```
finally
{
     myConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the connection outside the while loop, and then you try to open the same connection again, create a new connection inside the while loop or leave the connection open and do what needs to be done and then close it.