# C# - create has been successful, adding qty has been successful. but error apears 'the connection is already open.'

Tags: c#, mysql

guys..

I am training to create an existing bookstore app feature to add book stock and reduce book stock. when I create a stock added feature and save the transaction data of the stock addition, I get an error 'the connection is already open.' but I've closed all open connections. Please help me..

this is my code to show distributor id

```
public void loadDistributorID()
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select id from distributor";
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            distributorPasok.Items.Add(reader.GetString("id"));
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

this is my code to show book id

```
public void loadBukuID()
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select id from buku";
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            bukuPasok.Items.Add(reader.GetString("id"));
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

this is my code to add qty

```
public void increaseQty()
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "update buku set stok=stok + @jumlah where id=@id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jumlah", Convert.ToString(jumlahPasok.Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", bukuPasok.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

this is my code to add the transaction data of the stock addition

```
try
        {
            if (distributorPasok.Text == "" || bukuPasok.Text == "" || jumlahPasok.Value == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data harus terisi dengan valid!");
            } else
            {
                conn.Open();

                cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into pasok (id_distributor, id_buku, jumlah, tanggal) values (@distributor, @buku, @jumlah, @tanggal)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@distributor", distributorPasok.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buku", bukuPasok.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jumlah", Convert.ToString(jumlahPasok.Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanggal", Convert.ToDateTime(tanggalPasok.Text));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Pasok telah ditambah!");

                perbaruiPasok();

                conn.Close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

and I've called all the classes into the add button.

Comment: What is in the method `perbaruiPasok();`?

Comment: The last code sample doesn't close the connection if you get an exeption. Is the code executed in this order ? if the last part of the code you shared isn't called last, you can get this kind of exception

Comment: If you open/close connection(s) on each call you could also start using `using` - that way your connections will be closed automatically. Same for the command-instances you create on each call...

Comment: `using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{    conn.Open();  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn))` that might work better?

Comment: I agree with @Fran that the `using` statement would be a better option. However, you may also want to close the connection when you receive and exception. `...catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); conn.Close(); }` to prevent exceptions from keeping your connection open if you choose to keep the current implementation.

Comment: before I create that feature, I've created other CRUD features that use such code, and no prior problems. This is my full code https://pastebin.com/hyt1nwmA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The connection is already open* indicates that the connection is still open when `Open()` method executed. If you remove all unrelated lines which controls opening & closing connection excluding flow control statements (`if` and `try...catch` block) for related methods, this is what you get:

```
// Method with try...catch
public void MethodName()
{
    try
    {
        if (...)
        {
            // other stuff
        }
        else
        {
            conn.Open(); // --> opening DB connection

            // other stuff

            conn.Close(); // --> closing DB connection
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // exception handling
    }
}

// Other method
public void OtherMethodName()
{
    // opening connection - will trigger exception if conn.Close in MethodName not executed!
    conn.Open(); 

    // other stuff

    conn.Close();
}
```

When exception occurs between `conn.Open()` and `conn.Close()` command, it will go to `catch` clause but since `conn.Close()` is not declared there, the connection is still open when second `conn.Open()` executes.

What you need to fix is placing `conn.Close()` on [`finally` block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally) which always executed even an exception occurred inside `try` block:

```
try
{
    if (...)
    {
        // other stuff
    }
    else
    {
        conn.Open();

        // other stuff
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // exception handling
}
finally
{
    // always executed regardless of exception
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();
}
```

In much better way, it is recommended to use [`using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) which automatically calls `Dispose()` method (implicitly calls `Close()`) for `IDisposable` connection objects, see this example:

```
// declare connection string class-level instead of MySqlConnection
string connectionString = "server=localhost;database=buku;uid=fkrfdllh;pwd=*********"

try 
{
    if (empty_input)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("message text");
    }
    else
    {
        // wrap both MySqlConnection & MySqlCommand on using statements
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("[command_text]", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[param_name]", value);

                // other parameters here

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("[success_message]");

                // other methods
            }

        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Related issue:

[Why do I get a "connection is already open" error during a MySQL update statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896028/why-do-i-get-a-connection-is-already-open-error-during-a-mysql-update-statemen)